# How to get Class value to another class MVC

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program using MVC architecture but my model class values does not send to controller. If I write code in the model class to send values to the database it works, but when I write code in the controller class to send values to the database it doesn't work.

This is model class:

```
namespace MVCC.Control
{
    class DogControl
    {       
         private string Name;
         private int Age;

         public DogControl()
         {
         }
         public DogControl(string name, int age)
         {
             Name = name;
             Age = age;
         }

        public void SetName(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            return Name;
        }
        public void SetAge(int age)
        {
            Age = age;
        }
        public int GetAge()
        {
            return Age;
        }
```

This is the controller class:

```
class Dog : DogControl
    {
       //DogControl();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        DogControl ctrl = new DogControl();

 public void update()
        {


            try
            {
                Connection newcon = new Connection();
                newcon.connnew();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = Connection.conect;

                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE neelas.emp_login SET name='" +GetName() + "' WHERE emp_id = '" + GetAge() + "' ";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", GetAge());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",GetName());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Data update in database");
                MessageBox.Show(GetName());
               // MessageBox.Show(conGetAge());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

This is my button click event:

```
   private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = nameTxt.Text;
        int Age = Convert.ToInt32(AgeTxt.Text);

        Dog dg = new Dog();
        dg.update();


    }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you use get/set methods and not properties? Why is your dog "model" called `DogControl` and your controller class called `Dog`? That is very backwards...

Comment: Also *"but i wrote send values to database code in controller class it not worked"* is not a description of a problem. Please try to be precise on what it should do and what it does when you run it. "not worked" doesn't help us. Your code is very strange, you are updating an `emp` (employee?) table setting the name, and using the age as an ID??? You also define parameters, but never use them in the SQL...

Comment: Could you please update your sample code so it is clear what you call "model", "controller" and "view". Also consider clarifying what (if any) framework you use for your exercise. While editing post please remove that insane SQL update code (using string concatenation *and* parameter could cause comments/answers to go completely different direction).

Comment: I think you need to start learning mvc in more structured manner. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dog
{
    private string _name;
    private int _age;

    public Dog(string name, int age)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }

    public Dog setName(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;

        return this;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public Dog setAge(int age)
    {
        this._age = age;

        return this;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return this._age;
    }   
}

public class DogControl
{
    private Dog _dog;

    public DogControl(Dog dog)
    {
        _dog = dog;
    }

    public void update()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection newcon = new Connection();
            newcon.connnew();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = Connection.conect;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE neelas.emp_login SET name=@name WHERE emp_id = @emp_id ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", _dog.getAge());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",_dog.getName());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Data update in database");
            MessageBox.Show(GetName());
            // MessageBox.Show(conGetAge());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Name = nameTxt.Text;
    int Age = Convert.ToInt32(AgeTxt.Text);

    Dog dg = new Dog(Name, Age);
    DogControl control = new DogControl(dg);

    dg.update();
}
```

Comment: Please explain question (and your sample requires change to Dog class for no reason).

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio  Thank you very much it worked for me

Comment: @Chamikamaduranga you're welcome. Please vote up and mark as answer